# how to modiify an existing record in realm in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I want to update values in an existing data for a particular schema

```
class Car {}
Car.schema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    make:  'string',
  }
};
let realm = new Realm({schema: [Car,]});
realm.write(() => {
  let myCar = realm.create('Car', {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    miles: 2000,
  });
});
realm.write(() => {
  let myCar = realm.create('Car', {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    miles: 2000,
  });
});
realm.write(() => {
  let myCar = realm.create('Car', {
    model: 'Focus',
  });
})
```

Now If i want to update this 'model' property out of several records, how can I do it.

Comment: Have a collection, update that collection, and write out the output.

Answer (score 5):

To update properties on multiple records you will need to get the records from realm and then loop through them to make your changes. So after all of the writes (make sure that the callback functions have run already) you would do something like this.

```
const cars = realm.objects('Car');
realm.write(() => {
  cars.forEach(car => {
    // apply your changes to car here
    car.model = 'Some New Model';
  });
});
```

It's important to note that since these writes take place in callback functions you need to make sure that this code is running after the callbacks that you wrote in your example are complete.

Also, I assume that the three separate `realm.write` methods above are only for an example, but if you need to write multiple things to realm all at once make sure to consolidate all the writes in to a single `realm.write` if possible. With the few calls you have above there won't be any noticeable performance issues, but when you have a few hundred you are trying to write at one time you will run into pretty severe bottlenecks.

On another side note, if you're looking for a simple way to manage listening to changes in realm data I would suggest taking a look at [react-native-realm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-realm). *Full disclosure: it's a library I wrote, but I find it to be helpful in not having to remember to wire up and tear down event listeners every component mount and unmount.*